# Use vee-validate flags with Vuetify errors.collect

Tags: vuetify.js, vee-validate

I am using Vee Validate with Vuetify like this:

```
<v-text-field
v-model="email"
type='email'
required
v-validate="'required|email'"
:error-messages="errors.collect('email')"
label="E-mail"
data-vv-name="email"
ref="email"
required
></v-text-field>
```

I want to use some field flags shown in the docs like this:

```
<span v-show="errors.has('email') && fields.email.touched">{{ errors.first('email') }}</span>
```

I want to use the built in Vuetify form errors since they look nice but can not seem to get the flags to work. I have tried:

```
:error-messages="errors.collect('email') && fields.email.touched"
```

This clearly is not correct. Any ideas?

## Edit

I have added a code pen example, you will notice that as soon as you start typing in the email field you get an error in the confirm email field. What I am trying to do is only show the error if the field has an error and has been touched/changed.
https://codepen.io/tjquinn/pen/gKrVdX?&editors=101

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to rename your `fields bag` when adding `VeeValidate` to Vue in your `main.js` ? Sometimes conflicts happen whit global name `fields`.

I do it this way, in my `main.js` :

```
Vue.use(VeeValidate, {fieldsBagName: 'formFields'})
```

and in my code I add the prop `data-vv-scope="myFormName"` and access it like this :

```
this.formFields['$myFormName']['keyName'].touched
```

Comment: I tried you solution but it did not work for me. I added a code pen example above.